# how can i zoom in my web to 120%, and zoom the font-size to 150%?

Tags: html, css

in high-resolution, the components in my web seems a little small,  i want to zoom in my web to 120% in high-resolution, what's more, also I need to expand all the fonts to the original 1.5 times.

i set the css as following:

```
{
zoom: 1.2;
}
```

[image]
i zoom the web to 1.2, and then i need to continune to zoom the font-size to 5/4, so at last the font-size will be 1.2*5/4=1.5.

how can i do it?

if i add the following style to every text, i think it's inefficient 。

```
{font-size: 125%;}
```

so, is there any efficient way to zoom in the whole font-size in the web?

Comment: I can't help you but check out this article on zoom https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/

Comment: yeah, thank, however, i already zoom the web, now my issue is how to continune to zoom all the font-size in my  web。。

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
  body
  {
    transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
  }
```